# OnTouch works, but OnClickListener doesn't?

Tags: android, android-view, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I created a widget/control that I can reuse which I created by extending `RelativeLayout`. Then, in one of my Activities, I created a bunch of these widgets in a loop. However, I ran into an issue when I wanted to have each widget respond to a click.

I found that setting `OnTouchListener` works:

```
 this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
           //Triggers debug message
        }       
    });
```

but `OnClickListener` doesn't:

```
  this.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Doesn't trigger debug message  
        }

    });
```

Why is this?

Comment: Are you adding both of these to the same Object?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild - No, one at a time - comment the other out..

Comment: you have to return True in the onTouchListener to prevent the event from getting consumed.

Comment: @harvey_slash, actually returning True means that it **has** to be consumed. So not to consume it, you have to return false

Comment: i have returned false from ontouchlistener yet it not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a few things to check to make sure your views are clickable:

```
View.setClickable()
View.setEnabled()
View.setFocusable()
View.setFocusableInTouchMode()
```

Depending on the exact behavior you hope to get, you'll need to set one or more of those to on. Since you are getting onTouch events, my guess is that you need to setClickable.  But i'd have to see the view creation code to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried setting all of these to true, but it didn't work.

Comment: Setting my extended relative layout to "this.setClickable(true);" actually was the answer. I was using a "Toast" message as debug statement instead of logcat. Turns out I was using the wrong context object. Thanks bro...

Answer (score 53):

You should make sure that the TouchListener is not 'consuming' the touch event. If you return true from the `onTouch()` method, Android will consider it consumed and not pass it on to the other various touch handlers (which I am assuming will include the ClickListener).

You should do:

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        //Triggers debug message
        return false;
    }       
});
```

Comment: Worked for me. Returning false from onTouch makes the onClick work.

Answer (score 16):

Are you returning the boolean onTouch value properly?

From the docs:

> **onTouch()** - This returns a boolean to indicate
>   whether your listener consumes this
>   event. The important thing is that
>   this event can have multiple actions
>   that follow each other. So, if you
>   return false when the down action
>   event is received, you indicate that
>   you have not consumed the event and
>   are also not interested in subsequent
>   actions from this event. Thus, you
>   will not be called for any other
>   actions within the event, such as a
>   finger gesture, or the eventual up
>   action event.

**EDIT**

Found the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422358/android-custom-button-onclicklistener-is-not-getting-invoked) and just tried it out myself.

You need to use this `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` in your onTouchEvent code. After adding this the OnClickListener started working.

Comment: Interesting and good to know... However, when I test the onClick, I comment out the OnTouch

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Where in the touch event would this go? I tried replacing "return true" in my OnTouchListener - The "event" is a "MotionEvent" and the super class doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 5):

To perform this return false in your `onTouch()` like this:

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){    
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {   
            return false;
        }       
});
```

Comment: but this would disable your ontouch listener... this would be the same as deleting it out of your app.

Answer (score 2):

When you need both onClick and onTouch events on the same view, use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect).

Answer (score 2):

You can Implement an onClickListener via onTouchListener:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public final static int FINGER_RELEASED = 0;
        public final static int FINGER_TOUCHED = 1;
        public final static int FINGER_DRAGGING = 2;
        public final static int FINGER_UNDEFINED = 3;

        private int fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_RELEASED) fingerState = FINGER_TOUCHED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(fingerState != FINGER_DRAGGING) {
                        fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;

                        // Your onClick codes

                    }
                    else if (fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_TOUCHED || fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_DRAGGING;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                default:
                    fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you override the onMotionEvent() method for some reason and you need to return true/false in that case, you can manually trigger the OnClickListener() callback by calling this.performClick() inside the overridden onMotionEvent() just before you return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried returning false:

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return false;
    }       
});
```

and it didn't work, try this solution if you are using ScrollView. 
Add a LinearLayout inside the ScrollView. 
Set clickable to true in it.
Call setOnClickListener and setOnTouchListener from the LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <content... />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


LinearLayout linearlayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
linearlayout.setOnClickListener...
linearlayout.setOnTouchListener...
```