# Android - Alert stops onClickListeners from listening

Tags: android, alert, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

Been scratching my head on this one. I have the following code which simply looks at a pixel and identifies its color. Should it be a certain color, it will call an alert to pop up.

```
public void setClick(final View view)
{
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (count == 0) {
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                view.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
                if (Color.red(bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) == 232) {
                    alert();
                    count++;
                }
```

The XML for the onTouchListener is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/silLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cust_scroll"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="558dp"
    android:background="@drawable/silhoutte_front_ii"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="setClick"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toCustomize"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Next >>"
    android:onClick="toCustomize"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The alert is constructed as follows.

```
public void alert(){
    LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_scroll, null);

    TextView textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
    textview.setText("Your really long message.");
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    //alertDialog.setMessage("Here is a really long message.");
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancel", null);
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

The XML for the alert is as follows.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="hello" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, when the correct color is identified, the alert pops up no problem. Afterwards, however, the onTouchListener stops responding and will no longer call the alert. I understand that in the title I said the onClickListerns are breaking and this is an onTouchListener, but I have this very same issue elsewhere with an onClickListener. I cannot find any information on the subject but I know there is a simple solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your LogCat please?

Comment: Maybe this is too simplistic, but in the ontouchListener you increment count, then you check if the count ==0.  So won't this stop the effect of the listener? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283293/ontouch-works-but-onclicklistener-doesnt?rq=1 regarding the onclick issue.

Comment: Well that would do it, it was left over from something else and I didn't even notice, thanks! I'm a bit new, how do I select your answer?